# Iterating through nested firebase objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to iterate through nested firebase objects.

```
Publications-
            |
            |-Folder1------
            |             |-hdgjg76675e6r-
            |             |               |-Name
            |             |               |-Author
            |             |
            |             |+-hdgjdsf3275e6k
            |             |+-hd345454575e6f
            |+-Folder2
```

In publications I have folders and in folders I have objects (containing properties like. Name, Author)

I have iterated through folders till now.

```
snapshot.forEach(function (snapshot) {
    var key = snapshot.key();
    var obj = snapshot.val();
    console.log(key);
    //output => Folder1 , Folder2 etc
});
```

When I print **obj**

```
console.log(obj);
```

It displays

[image]

How do I iterate through **obj** variable as it contains `hdgjg76675e6r` , `hdgjdsf3275e6k` etc and further?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You `obj` is just a normal javascript object, you can just use a simple for loop:

```
for(var key in obj) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
}
```

or you can use again a `forEach` on your snapshot:

```
folderSnapshot.forEach(function (objSnapshot) {
    objSnapshot.forEach(function (snapshot) {
        var val = snapshot.val();
        console.log(val); // Should print your object
    });
});
```

Comment: PS: you can copy an object from chrome devtools right clicking it > save as temp variable. It will print something like `temp1`, if you write in chrome console `copy(temp1)` you'll be able to paste it on any editor ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip sir. :)

Answer (score 2):

Will the tree increase in depth? If not, then the best solution here is to just do a double for loop.

```
snapshot.forEach(function (snapshot) {
    var key = snapshot.key();
    var obj = snapshot.val();
    console.log(key);
    //output => Folder1 , Folder2 etc

    obj.forEach(function (book) {
        var title = book.title;
        var author = book.author;
    });
});
```

No need to over-engineer things, in my opinion.

Comment: var key = snapshot.key, you should not call as a function

Answer (score 1):

Heres simple way how you can get your object of objects to array of objects:

```
var myObject = {key1: {name: 'hello'}, key2: {name: 'hello2'}}; 
var myArrayOfObject = Object.values(myObject);

console.log(myArrayOfObject);
// Result: (2) [Object, Object]
```